# How edit code template ASP MVC 4 CRUD Generator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to alter the default code genaration of MVC CRUD ASP . NET.
Visual Studio.It generates pages of "Edit.cshtml/Insert.cshtml/Delete.cshtml"
I want to translate "Edit" to "Alterar" - "Insert" to "Inserir", and I would like that the razor file to be called "Alterar.cshtml" instead of "Edit.cshtml"

How can I do that?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Based on [this excellent blogpost by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) I changed the default template in a few steps. The difference between Scott's approach and mine is that he apparently made it in a way that keeps the global default but gives him a separate generator for each project. Since I didn't get it working immediately, I opted to instead just change the global template.

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddController` (some parts of the URI may vary in your situation
2. Optionally: grant yourselves write privileges on `Controller.tt`
3. Open `Controller.tt` in an editor of your choice and change what you want to change. Note that these are [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) so you have a wide variety of tools to your disposition if you want to do more advanced stuff.
4. Create a new ASP.NET MVC project
5. Go to the "Controllers" folder and add a new controller (*not* an api controller)

You don't have to change anything to get a differently named view: the view, including the file in which it is stored, is generated based on the name of the action method that creates it. If you generate the view from `Alterar` then the popup window will present you with the name "Alterar" for the file.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I found the solution, I was changing the wrong file, I change the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddController\ControllerWithContext.tt and it works! Thanks!!!